# How much does the Tears to Tiara anime relate to the visual novel?

Tags: tears-to-tiara

I know that the artwork used in the anime is based off the Play Station release which was a remake of the original PC visual novel (major designs of almost every character, most notably Lyrl looking a lot older and Rathy looking more like a girl).

I'm wondering how much of the plot of the anime is related to the original visual novel?